# Why UITextView white color Highlight when tableview cell selected in Xcode 11?

Tags: ios, uitextview, ios13, xcode11

The UITextView white color (click here) gets highlight when I tap on tableview cell.

This is not happening older version of xCode. This is only happens in xCode 11.0.

Happened in xCode 11.0 build as below.

[image]

I am expecting and already happening in previous xCodes as below :

[image]

I Tried to make the clear color of UITextView but no luck.

Any idea why this happened for different xCode build? Please reply if you find any solution.

Comment: Are you using a default table view cell or a custom / prototype cell? What is the background color of your cell? of your cell's `Content View`? of the label? of any other views you've added (if it's a custom cell)?

Comment: @DonMag all are default colors. And lable background color is clear. For your information. its working perfectly with xCode 10 but when moved to 11. this issue come. So I wonder is this os specific issue or what?

Comment: Yes, there have been changes - see Apple's [iOS 13 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios_ipados_release_notes/ios_13_release_notes), specifically where it states *The UITableViewCell class no longer changes the backgroundColor or isOpaque properties of the contentView and any of its subviews when cells become highlighted or selected.* However, with a default cell, the cell background, content view and label(s) all have `.clear` as background color, so it looks the same as before. Double-check all of your cell elements.

Comment: Ah - just realized you are talking about a `UITextView` in the cell... so, yeah, make sure **it** has background color set to `.clear` as well. If it's still white, use Debug View Hierarchy to inspect the elements.